# C# Callback after http GET/Post completes

Tags: .net, windows-phone-8.1, task, c#-5.0

I would like my Sign Up class to be able to determine the response from my server.  In order for that to happen, some form of callback needs to be created from my Newtwork Client class Request Handler.  I cant figure out how to best achieve this.  below is the working code that I have.   Further below is exactly what I am trying to simulate from Objective-C

```
public class SignUp{
 private async void createUser()
    {
        RequestHandler client = new RequestHandler();
        CreatePerson person = new CreatePerson();
        person.FirstName=this.firstNameText.Text;
        person.LastName=this.lastNameText.Text;
        person.Location="POINT(0 0)";
        person.Major = this.majorText.Text;
        person.UserName = this.userNameText.Text;
     //   person.Major =;
    await RequestHandler.CreatePerson(person);


    }
}
```

Request Handler class

```
 public class RequestHandler
    {


   public static async Task CreatePerson(CreatePerson person)
           {
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://studytree2.azurewebsites.net/api/");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        HttpResponseMessage response;
        // HTTP POST

        response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("Profile/CreateProfile", person );
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {

        }
    }
          }
    }
```

OBJECTIVE-C code

```
-(void)CreateUser
{
 [load doAlert:@"Registering" body:@"Submitting..." duration:0 done:^(DoAlertView *alertView) {

}];

[[RequestHandler shared]createPersonUsername:userNameText Firstname:firstName Lastname:lastName Password:passwordText Email:emailText Major:major success:^{
        [load hideAlert];

        if(currentImage !=nil)
        {
            [postPhoto postimageProfileImage:currentImage];
        }

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
        [self.delegate SignUpDidCompleteSuccess];
    }];
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        [load hideAlert];
        DoAlertView * alert =[[DoAlertView alloc]init];

        alert.bDestructive=YES;
        NSString * errorString;
        if(operation.response.statusCode==409)
        {
            errorString=@"Email already registered";
        }
        else if(operation.response.statusCode==405)
        {
            errorString=@"User name already exist";
        }
        else if(operation.response.statusCode==501)
        {
            errorString=@"Your university is not supported yet. :(";
        }
        else if(operation.response.statusCode == 415)
        {
            errorString=@"Your email is not valid. Please enter a active email";
        }
        else
        {
            errorString=@"Could not register (check connection)";
        }

        [alert doYes:errorString yes:^(DoAlertView *alertView) {

        }];
    }];
```

Create RequestHandler in Objective C

```
 -(void)createPersonUsername:(NSString *)username Firstname:(NSString  *)firstname Lastname:(NSString *)lastName Password:(NSString *)password Email: (NSString *)email Major:(NSString *)major success:(void (^)())successBlock  failure:(void (^)(AFHTTPRequestOperation *, NSError *))failureBlock
  {
 double x= [LocationTracker   sharedLocationManager].location.coordinate.longitude;
 double y= [LocationTracker sharedLocationManager].location.coordinate.latitude;
  NSString * locationString =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"POINT(%f %f)",x,y ];
  NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:username,@"UserName",firstname,@"FirstName",password,@"Password",email,@"Email",lastName,@"LastName",major,@"Major",locationString, @"location", nil];
NSURL *baseUrl=[NSURL URLWithString:KBaseUrl];

manager = [[AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager]initWithBaseURL:baseUrl];
manager.requestSerializer=[AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
 [manager POST:@"/api/Profile/CreateProfile" parameters:dictionary success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

     successBlock();
 } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
     failureBlock(operation,error);

 }];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know much about Objective-C but In C# you can achieve this by using event

```
public class RequestHandler
{
    //Need to create event Handler
    public event EventHandler DataReceivedHandler = null;


    public async Task CreatePerson(CreatePerson person)
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://studytree2.azurewebsites.net/api/");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            HttpResponseMessage response;
            // HTTP POST

            response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("Profile/CreateProfile", person);
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode && DataReceivedHandler!=null)
            {
               var responseBodyAsText = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

               DataReceivedHandler(this, new ResponseData { Data = responseBodyAsText });
            }
        }
    }
}




public class SignUp
{
    private async void createUser()
    {
        RequestHandler client = new RequestHandler();
        CreatePerson person = new CreatePerson();
        person.FirstName = this.firstNameText.Text;
        person.LastName = this.lastNameText.Text;
        person.Location = "POINT(0 0)";
        person.Major = this.majorText.Text;
        person.UserName = this.userNameText.Text;
        //   person.Major =;
        client.DataReceivedHandler += client_DataReceivedHandler;
        await client.CreatePerson(person);


    }

    void client_DataReceivedHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // this event trigger when your web request complete.
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

You need to some modification but I am using same code for my apps..and its working fine. Hope this will help you.

Comment: I dont quiet understand.  DataReceiveHandler can be used to call back? When I try to pass a object back in the second parameter I receive an error.

Comment: if u want to pass object then you should pass `object` instead of `this`